# Issue with html5's localStorage, storing the color theme of my menu

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Im kind of a newbie so indeph suggestions or explanations would be wesome.

What I want to do:

I have a settings menu with the option to change the background color of the menu itself, you can navigate the color options using two different classes, .rest and .plus, to go own and up throught the color options. The color options are stored in an array as strings.

My intention is to use localStorage in order to keep the user selected color option after page/session load.

My issue:
currently only the default color applies, navigating throught the color options works but applying the color doesn't. Probably because I'm not storing the local vars correctly.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
colores = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
var i = 0;
$('.colorines').text(colores[i]);

localStorage.getItem('color');
switch(color) {
    case 'yellow':
        $('.postit').removeClass('green').removeClass('purple').removeClass('blue').addClass('yellow');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 136)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 136)');
        break;
    case 'green':
        $('.postit').removeClass('blue').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('purple').addClass('green');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(146, 255, 134)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(146, 255, 134)');
        break;
    case 'blue':
        $('.postit').removeClass('green').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('purple').addClass('blue');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(135, 255, 216)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(135, 255, 216)');
        break;
 case 'purple':
        $('.postit').removeClass('blue').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('green').addClass('purple');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(248, 135, 255)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(248, 135, 255)');
        break;
    default:
        
}

$('.rest').click(function () {
if( i > 0){
colores[i--];
$('.colorines').text(colores[i]);
localStorage.setItem('color', colores[i]);
switch(color) {
    case 'yellow':
        $('.postit').removeClass('green').removeClass('purple').removeClass('blue').addClass('yellow');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 136)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 136)');
        break;
    case 'green':
        $('.postit').removeClass('blue').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('purple').addClass('green');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(146, 255, 134)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(146, 255, 134)');
        break;
    case 'blue':
        $('.postit').removeClass('green').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('purple').addClass('blue');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(135, 255, 216)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(135, 255, 216)');
        break;
 case 'purple':
        $('.postit').removeClass('blue').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('green').addClass('purple');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(248, 135, 255)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(248, 135, 255)');
        break;
    default:
        
}
}
});

$('.plus').click(function () {
if(i < colores.length){
colores[i++];
alert(color);
$('.colorines').text(colores[i]);
localStorage.setItem('color', colores[i]);
switch(color) {
    case 'yellow':
        $('.postit').removeClass('green').removeClass('purple').removeClass('blue').addClass('yellow');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 136)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 136)');
        break;
    case 'green':
        $('.postit').removeClass('blue').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('purple').addClass('green');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(146, 255, 134)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(146, 255, 134)');
        break;
    case 'blue':
        $('.postit').removeClass('green').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('purple').addClass('blue');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(135, 255, 216)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(135, 255, 216)');
        break;
 case 'purple':
        $('.postit').removeClass('blue').removeClass('yellow').removeClass('green').addClass('purple');
  $('.settingsin').css('background-color','rgb(248, 135, 255)');
  $('.settingsout').css('background-color','rgb(248, 135, 255)');
        break;
    default:
        
}
}
});







});
```

```css
.postit {
  position:absolute; 
  overflow:hidden;
  left:1070px; 
  top:-140px; 
  padding-left:10px;
  line-height: 1;   
  width: 275px;    
  margin: 0px;    
  min-height:250px;
  max-height:250px;
  padding-top:35px; 
  border-top:60px solid #fdfd86;
  font-family:'Reenie Beanie';    
  font-size:22px;      
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
  display:inline-block;    
}

.yellow{background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%);}
.green{background: linear-gradient(135deg, #93FF87 81%,#93FF87 82%,#93FF87 82%,#CBFFC7 100%);}
.blue{background: linear-gradient(135deg, #87FFD8 81%,#87FFD8 82%,#87FFD8 82%,#C7FFF5 100%);}
.purple{background: linear-gradient(135deg, #F887FF 81%,#F887FF 82%,#F887FF 82%,#FFC7FF 100%);}
 
.postit:after {     
  content: "";
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:-1;
  right:-0px; 
  bottom:20px;
  width:200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow:2px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  -moz-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.menu{
 list-style:none; 
 bottom:3px; 
 position:absolute; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 font-weight:300; 
 width:200px;
 z-index:1;
}

.menu  li{font-size:21px; margin-top:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postit yellow">
  <ul class="menu">
 <li><span>Menu color: </span ><span class="rest" style="cursor:pointer;">< </span><span class="colorines"></span><span class="plus" style="cursor:pointer;" > ></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The second part of this line shouldn't have quote I think: `localStorage.setItem('color', 'colores[i]');`-> `localStorage.setItem('color', colores[i]);`

Comment: in this case colores[i] is a string, are you sure about that?

Comment: pretty sure, you're probably trying to store the colors (like "yellow", or "green") if you save that string you'll have it in the localstorage just like you wrote it there ("colores[i]"). Try logging the stored color: console.log(localStorage.getItem('color'));

Comment: Yes you're right about the "", I tried logging the color and it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: color is not defined